# Spring Data MongoDB not working on Spring 3.0

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, maven, spring-mvc

I am making a `Spring User login` interface where I need to store User details in a `mongodb` database.

I am using `Spring 3.0`, and can't get to work `Spring-data-mongodb` in my project as I read somewhere that it needs a higher version of Spring.

How can I make `Spring-mongo-db` work in my current project or how can I update the dependencies properly in my `pom.xml` ?

Here is my current `pom.xml` :

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>controller</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-security-ldap-embedded</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>spring-security-ldap-embedded Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<dependencies>

<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.1</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.14</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
    <artifactId>apacheds-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
   <version>1.8.4.RELEASE</version>
   <type>jar</type>
   <exclusions>
     <exclusion>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
   <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.2</version>
   <type>jar</type>
</dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
<finalName>spring-security-ldap-embedded</finalName>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.5</source>
      <target>1.5</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>    
</build>
```

Here is the current `mongo-java-driver` and other `mongo` dependencies :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.4.RELEASE</version>
  <type>jar</type>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
  <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.2</version>
  <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

My securityconfig.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.1.xsd">

<!-- This is where we configure Spring-Security  -->

<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" >

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/common" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>

        <security:form-login
            login-page="/login"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"
            default-target-url="/main/common"/>

        <security:logout 
            invalidate-session="true"
            logout-success-url="/login"
            logout-url="/logout"/>

</security:http>

<!-- 
        For authentication:
        user-search-filter: the attribute name that contains the user name 
    user-search-base: the base path where to find user information

    For authorization:
    group-search-filter: the attribute name that contains the full dn of a user
    group-search-base: the base path where to find role information
    group-role-attribute: the attribute name that contains the role type
    role-prefix: the prefix to be added when retrieving role values

        For server access:
    manager-dn: the full dn of the person that has access to an LDAP server
    manager-password: the password of the person that has access to an LDAP server
-->

<security:authentication-manager>
        <security:ldap-authentication-provider  
                user-search-filter="(uid={0})"
                user-search-base="ou=users"
                group-search-filter="(uniqueMember={0})"
                group-search-base="ou=groups"
                group-role-attribute="cn"
                role-prefix="ROLE_">
        </security:ldap-authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<!-- 
        Use an embedded LDAP server. We need to declare the location of the LDIF file
        We also need to customize the root attribute default is "dc=springframework,dc=org"
    -->

<security:ldap-server ldif="classpath:mojo.ldif"  root="o=mojo"/>
```

My applicationcontext.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd">

<!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
<context:annotation-config />

<!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered as Spring beans.
        For example @Controller and @Service. Make sure to set the correct base-package-->
<context:component-scan base-package="controller" />

<!-- Configures the annotation-driven Spring MVC Controller programming model.
Note that, with Spring 3.0, this tag works in Servlet MVC only!  -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way to get it working is upgrade your spring version.

> Spring Data MongoDB 1.x binaries requires JDK level 6.0 and above, and Spring Framework 4.2.6.RELEASE and above.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#requirements

---

EDIT

- Delete your existing .m2/repository completely or jars and folders related to spring and mongo
- Modify your pom.xml and specify the appropriate spring version.
- Do mvn clean install

Hope it solves the issues at your end.

Comment: But I tried upgrading my pom.xml, but the project ceases to deploy. What other changes should I do in my project ? How should I properly update my other files ?

Comment: Try the changes which I added in the EDIT section of my answer

Comment: Actually I am using an IDE (Netbeans), in which I modified the pom.xml and replaced all older versions by their latest counterpart (4.3 and 4.1 for spring-security), but I have some other `securityconfig.xml` and `applicationcontext.xml` files, which need to changed, How to do this ?

Comment: You can use any IDE, but still you can do the steps which I mentioned in the edit section. Go to the respective path/location(say D:/myworkspace/myproject) in which you have the code base, open a command prompt or terminal in that location and perform all the steps listed in the edit section and then in your IDE update the dependencies.